# Add a code editor to a textarea via console/bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, codemirror, ace-editor

I've run into an issue where I'm developing pages on a CMS which is out of my control, and I'm editing increasingly complex pages with nothing more than a textarea.

Initially I'm creating the pages in my code editor, then copying the HTML into the textarea. Keeping the local and CMS code in sync by hand.

This workflow sucks.

I'd like to have code highlighting, etc while I work within the CMS. Is there any way I can add a code editor like [Ace](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/build/textarea/editor.html) or [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) to the textarea via bookmarklet or console command? I've tried using the [Ace Bookmarket Builder](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/build/textarea/editor.html) but I don't know if it's been designed to work on any page, or just github.

Edit:
I don't think I was clear enough above. I'm just an end user on this CMS, I have no ability to change how it functions on the backend. I literally just need a bookmarklet that finds the textarea and applies a code editor to it.

Comment: I do not believe you will be ever able to fully customize a browser's textarea to your individual needs like a fully featured texteditor or ide.
Maybe there is a way to automatically pull and push the changes to your cms by a scripting approach for example by using tools like selenium or curl.

Comment: CodeMirror's .fromTextArea does 90% of your work. you might have to shim the styles and you'll need to bind some buttons for input/output, but it works. see http://danml.com/codemirror/embed/ for an example

Comment: Ace Bookmarket Builder Is designed to work on any page

Comment: Have you tried Tampermonkey? You can add your own JavaScript to any web page. Tampermokey is a Chrome extension, there are similar extensions for other browsers. http://tampermonkey.net/

Comment: Did you try the advanced code editor plugin for wp?

Comment: **dandavis** I'll take a look at that page, thanks!
**auser** - Unfortunately I couldn't get it work. The instructions are quite sparse. I tried dragging it to my bookmarks bar, then clicking it on the page with the textarea I need "enhanced" to no effect
**zoranc** The CMS is a custom job, not WP. Sadly, no plugin support.

Answer (score 1):

both tinymce and syntaxhighlighter are packages that are not tied to a CMS, so if yours is custom then you will want to try to use these together, I have heard of some success in this adventure in the Drupal (there is actually a project for it currently) arena but you may be looking at a bit of work to do so custom. there is chatter about this http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=22901 <-here with even a plugin to tinymce :) hope this gets the ideas going!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I'm just an end-user on this CMS. I have no ability to add or change how the CMS works. I literally just need to click on a bookmarklet and have the textarea convert to a code editor.